# How to select a specific date-time rows into DataFrame directly from a Excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

My csv file has 192 columns, 83952 rows of data for two years. The first column is Time. This column data is in `datetime64[ns]` format. However, I want to read specific rows belonging to a specific date-time. My code is given below:

```
valid_data = ['2016-08','2017-02','2017-06','2017-08','2018-02']
df = pd.read_excel('dataset.xlsx',sheet_name=1,skiprows=[lambda x:~(x.strftime('%Y-%m')==valid_data)]
print(df.shape)
```

Output is:

```
(83952, 192)
```

Looks like, my code did not work well as it reads all rows. How to read those specific rows directly from csv file?

Comment: Not sure where a CSV file comes into this - you're dealing with an Excel workbook... in short - you can't. You could directly use the Excel reader library to open the file, iterate the rows and build the subset yourself, however, note that libraries generally load the entire file into memory anyway (that's how Excel documents are structured) or they attempt to mmap a lot of it anyway... so you gain nothing by not just loading it and post-filtering out what you don't want.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for correction. So, I should read the file completely and then iterate rows? If so, How to do that?

Comment: Not iterate it... just subset the DataFrame accordingly on the criteria you want... probably something along the lines of `new_df = df[~df['some_date_col'].dt.strftime('%Y-m').isin(valid_data)]` or something...

Comment: @JonClements I did this code and got it: `df = df[df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m').isin(valid_data)]`. That's fine. However, I wanted to get same result using this code `df = df[df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')==[valid_data]]`. It gave error `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)` . How to get same result using this second code?

Comment: You don't... `==` and `.isin` are completely different things... You want to check that that date is *one of* the items in the list... When you do `if 'something' = ['a', 'b', 'c']` it's basically telling you that makes no sense as a comparison... what would you expect it to do?

Comment: is it not possible get the result using `==` ?

Comment: No... because it's meaningless for the actual thing you want... What you want is `.isin`... Do you use `x * y` when you want to divide two numbers because you'd really rather use that operator instead? :p